# import all references of a paper into a bibtex file

Tags: citations, reference-managers, bibtex

I have a paper that has say 100 references. I'd like to use a lot of them as references to a paper I'm writing, but it seems pretty laborious to go on each and everyone of them, search in google scholar and get the bibtex info. 
Is there a tool available that given a paper\pdf\book etc, harvests all the references of that paper into a list or bibtex file?

Comment: This has been discussed on TeX.SE: [How to automatically extract cited documents from pdf to .bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364023/128923)

Comment: The first option is to use a database that is mostly related to physics (I couldnt find there the paper I wanted), the other option is a tool that might be good but is not free...

Comment: This question sounds strange to me every time I read it. If you're writing a paper, you should include in your references only those sources you've actually accessed, read, and used, not just an arbitrary list of related references from someone else's paper.

Answer (score 3):

There would be a quick approach if you know how to code:

1. Take the DOI of that publication.
2. Use that DOI to access the [OpenCitations API](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1). (Example [here](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/references/10.1177/1369148118786043).)
3. From the API, extract all the DOIs that are referenced in the `citing` field.
4. Loop each referenced DOI through a DOI-to-BibTeX-converter (such as [doi2bib](https://pypi.org/project/doi2bib/) in Python, or [CrossCite](https://citation.crosscite.org/))

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [great answer above](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/161536/166991), here's a tiny shell snippet that, given an input `doi` of a paper, will generate a `.bib` file containing the references of that paper.

```
export DOI="..." # put your input DOI here (not as a URL, just the DOI itself)
curl -X GET "https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/references/$DOI" | jq --raw-output ".[]|.cited" | doi2bib -i - -o "${DOI//[\/-]/_}-refs.bib"
```

To make this work, need to first install `jq` (available from any package manager, e.g. `brew` on macos) and `doi2bib` (available via `pip`).